# How can I make my radio buttons required

Tags: html, radio-button

I have two radio buttons in a form in the same radio group :

```
<li><input name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" /><label class="label_gender" required> Male</label></li>
<li><input name="gender" type="radio" value="Female" /><label class="label_gender" required> Female</label></li>
```

I want to make this radio group required, as you see I used the `required` attribute for both f them, but it doesn't work.

for other inputs as text or email, the `required` attribute works fine.

How can I make my radio buttons required ?

Comment: This should help :) 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-in-an-input-field-with-type-radio][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-in-an-input-field-with-type-radio

Answer (score 3):

The `required` attribute should be added to the `input` element, **not** the `label` element.

Change your markup to:

```
<li><input name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" required /><label class="label_gender"> Male</label></li>
<li><input name="gender" type="radio" value="Female" required /><label class="label_gender"> Female</label></li>
```