# How to require radio button selection in html5 form

Tags: html, forms, validation, radio-button, form-submit

html 5 form contains two radio buttons.
How to force user to select one radion button before submitting form ?
I tried to use required but there is not radio button group, required shoult applited to group.

```
<form action="/Home/Sendtitle" method="post">
<p>
  Title*  <span>
    <span>
      <span>
        <input name="staatus" type="radio" value="Mister" autofocus>&nbsp;
        <span>Mister</span>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input name="staatus" type="radio" value="Missis">&nbsp;
        <span>Missis</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="submit" value="Send title" >
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-in-an-input-field-with-type-radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property required as its a boolean attribute that solve ur problem. required="required"

Comment: Drop the `="required"` part.  From the HTML5 spec:  _"A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value."_

Answer (score 10):

Use `required` attribute.

```
<input name="staatus" type="radio" value="Missis" required>
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to set the required-attribute for one input of the radiogroup, but you can set it for all.

```
<form action="/Home/Sendtitle" method="post">
<p>
  Title*  <span>
    <span>
      <span>
        <input name="staatus" type="radio" value="Mister" autofocus required>&nbsp;
        <span>Mister</span>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input name="staatus" type="radio" value="Missis">&nbsp;
        <span>Missis</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="submit" value="Send title" >
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: Anyone know the current state of browsers still implementing this incorrectly  by requiring every radio option having the required attribute?

Answer (score 0):

And you can use it once:

```
<span>
    <input name="status" type="radio" value="Mister" autofocus required="required">&nbsp;
    <span>Mister</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input name="status" type="radio" value="Missis">&nbsp;
    <span>Missis</span>
  </span>
```