# How can I prevent them from inserting their answer/post ? (And how to add an error message?)

Tags: mysql, radiobuttonlist

I'm using this code for my questionnaire, how can I prevent them from inserting their answers/post? If they did not yet clicked all the radio buttons, that is given within the system which is the questions? And how to add an error message besides the question?

[image: Questionnaire Picture1]

---

[image: Questionnaire Picture2]

```
if(isset($_POST['question']))
{
    $AddQuery = "INSERT INTO tblevaluate (evaluateid,professorid,professorname,studentid,course,section,subjectid,subjectname) VALUES ('','$server_professorid','$server_name',' $username','$course','$section','$server_subjectid','$server_subject')";
    mysql_query($AddQuery, $connect);
    $id = mysql_insert_id();

    foreach($_POST['question'] as $questionId => $answer)
    {
        $AddQuery = "INSERT INTO tblanswer (answervalue,evaluateid,professorid,professorname,studentid,course,section,subjectid,subjectname) VALUES ($answer,$id,$server_professorid,'$server_name',$username,'$course','$section',$server_subjectid,'$server_subject')";
        mysql_query($AddQuery, $connect);
        header('Location: evaluate.php');
    }
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<strong>" . $row["questionno"] . ".</strong> " . $row["question"] . "";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type = radio name = 'question[". $row ["questionid"] . "]'  value = '5'/><label>5</label>";
    echo "<input type = radio name = 'question[". $row ["questionid"] . "]'  value = '4'/><label>4</label>";
    echo "<input type = radio name = 'question[". $row ["questionid"] . "]'  value = '3'/><label>3</label>";
    echo "<input type = radio name = 'question[". $row ["questionid"] . "]'  value = '2'/><label>2</label>";
    echo "<input type = radio name = 'question[". $row ["questionid"] . "]' value = '1'/><label>1</label>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<hr size = 5 color = black noshade >";
}
```

Comment: [Make the radio groups required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field) is the simplest way to prevent form submission. To be 'truly safe' you'd also need to ensure that all the values are set to allowable values on the server, but *meh* - not really any point even talking about that when there is *Blatant SQL Injection* vulnerabilities. Also, your tables are poorly normalized.

Comment: Use javascript to verify whether radio buttons are set on submitting the form.

Comment: @user2864740 yes, it is poorly normalized because I'm using phpmyadmin as a database. I'm going to review the link that you gave me.

Comment: @r2_d3 I'll take a look on it, thanks.

Comment: @user2864740 MAN, THANKS A LOT, IT WORKS PERFECTLY FINE! :) Thanks be to God for your patience on answering this question, May God Bless you!

Answer (score 1):

The Answer came from user2864740

[Make the radio groups required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field) is the simplest way to prevent form submission. To be 'truly safe' you'd also need to ensure that all the values are set to allowable values on the server, but meh - not really any point even talking about that when there is Blatant SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Also, your tables are poorly normalized. – user2864740