# HTML5 form Required Attribute displays no message for input type radio

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a database-driven test and just added the required attribute  before the closing tags on my labels. I discovered that if I don't answer a question, then hit the submit button, the page jumps up to the unanswered question, and a message is displayed - something like "You need to choose an answer" or whatever.

It's a great feature, but it doesn't work with questions with an input type = radio. If I don't answer one of those questions, then hit the submit button, the form doesn't process anything, but it doesn't display a message alerting the user to the problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

P.S. My script doesn't allow me to insert "required" in just one element. If I insert "required," it automatically displays in ALL checkboxes.

```
<label for="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'"><input type="checkbox" name="q'.$QID.'[]" id="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'" value="'.$Value.'" required> '.$QA.'</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the required attribute for one input of the radio button group.

```
<form>
  <label for="input1">male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="input1" value="male" required>

  <label for="input2">female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="input2" value="female">

  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

A very important thing you need to remember is that the radio and checkbox inputs are grouped by the name attribute. So, setting required on any one of the inputs (among a group of inputs having the same name) would work. If, on the other hand, you miss out on the name attribute, it won't work as you'd expect.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the other problem I'm trying to solve...since my display is database-driven, I can only insert "required" in ALL the checkboxes or none of them. I asked about that @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809395/displaying-required-in-just-one-checkbox-dynamic-display

Comment: Why dont you use 'required' only in then first checkbox of a group using a condition written in php?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that; is there a way to write a PHP switch that says "display 'required' only if 1) the choices are checkboxes, and 2) insert it only in the FIRST checkbox"?