# How can i create HTML5 like required alert for radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, css

For the **input type text**, if i add required attribute, my form won't submit and browser will focus on required field and alert will say please fill this field.
For the **input type radio**, if i add required attibute, my form won't submit but also it does not provide me any alert or focus on the radio which is unchecked.
If this is not an in-built functionality for HTML5, can i in some way create it and make it look like the same as it looks for text inputs so that style integrity is also preserved?

Comment: I think you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8287779/2486583

Comment: @JamesIrwin i'm looking for more than that. It surely does validate the form but does not give an alert.

Comment: What validation library are you using? Are you using mvc? Do you have a validation summary?

Comment: @Harry no library. Just plain HTML/JS.

Comment: Are you using Safari? If so, there's a bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28649

Answer (score -1):

This code works well, if you not select radio, form will not submit. If you select one and enter text in textbox, form will submit.

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="1" required>
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="2" required>
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="3" required>
    <input type="text" name="two" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
<form>
```

Checked on latest version of Google Chrome. **May be you found a bug in your browser, try to update it.**

Comment: if you read my question carefully, i'm not denying that the form validation fails, i'm saying it does not give an alert for radio

Answer (score -1):

Beside `required` radio button *alerts* work *"perfectly fine"* in Chrome...

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lewomen/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

it **makes no sense at all to have an alert for a radio button, that's silly.**
If you have a radio button:

1. there's absolutely no need to have only one radio button. → Use checkboxes.
2. there's absolutely no reason to have all radio buttons *unchecked* initially.
3. one must be checked by default - **and it's your job to do so**
4. logically there's no need to popup alerts like "This radio button is required" - therefore neither to set a `required` attribute to a radio button.

if you still don't understand why... well simple because radios are used as UI switch states. Only one can and **must** be `checked`. If you make them all initially unchecked - and a client unintentionally hits a radio - **he's dead in the devil's loop, because once you enter the circle there's no way out**.  Therefore makes no sense to have all *blanks* in the first place. You cannot undo... (well, unless you have another silly checkbox or something that says "uncheck all radio buttons!" nonsense).

Comment: You haven't met my clients... ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry I don't believe this *client* stories. in 8Y of front-end web development if I said to my client that his idea is stupid - they always believed me. That's also your job.

Comment: Totally agree. I always suggest, that if they must "require" a radio button, that they add a "None" option that is initially checked. Then the validation is that the "None" option is not checked.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this is indeed a client story :P otherwise i wouldn't have bothered to think about radio button validation as it's best practice to have one value checked always.

Comment: @SumitNalawade :) well in that case hope to have unveiled the best practice and helped you to get to (hopefully/eventually) a better UI solution :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan now we're talking ;) 100% agreed