# Make checkboxes required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I already looked to similar questions but I still can't figure out how to fix it. On my webpage, I have some radio checkboxes which I would like to be required before going to the next question.

I have the following partial code:

```
 <p>
   Select the option that fits most to you<br><br>
   <label>
   <input type="radio" name="typesport" value="teamsport" > 
   I prefer a teamsport</label><br>
   <label>
   <input type="radio" name="typesport" value="individual"> 
   I prefer an individual sport</label><br>
 </p>
<a href="#question2" class="tm-bordered-btn">Next question</a>
```

Can someone help me with getting a javascript code, that actually works for all radio-boxes, where you could only go to the next question when 1 radio-box is selected?

Cheers,
Max

Edit: What I've tried so far is the following:
I added "required" to the label, so it looked like this:

```
 <label><input type="radio" name="typesport" value="teamsport" required> I prefer a teamsport</label><br>
```

I also added the ID to the button:

```
 <a href="#question2" class="tm-bordered-btn" id="checkBtn">Next question</a>
```

Furthermore, I used this JS script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
        checked = $("input[type=radio]:checked").length;

        if(!checked) {
          alert("You must check at least one radio.");
          return false;
        }

      });

  });
```

However, this works fine for only one question. When I add this to all the other questions, I still can go to the following question when I click on the button Next question, and that is not what I want.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please understand SO is not a free coding service. You have to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio boxes are fairly simple in nature in that you should always have at least one option in a radio-group checked by default. Preferably a *N/A* or *'Please Select'* option.

In which case you would want to validate against the *'Please Select'* option instead:

```js
//when user clicks <a> element
$(".next-button").click(function() {
  //group on radio button name and test if checked
  if ($("input[name='typesport']:checked").val() == 'select') {
    alert('Nothing is checked!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Select the option that fits most to you<br><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="typesport" value="select" checked="true" > Please Select </label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="typesport" value="teamsport" > I prefer a teamsport</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="typesport" value="individual"> I prefer an individual sport</label><br>
</p>
<a href="#question2" class="tm-bordered-btn next-button">Next question</a>
```

**However**

If you really want to validate that an option has been checked:

This should work:

```js
//when user clicks <a> element
$(".next-button").click(function()
{
  //group on radio button name and test if checked
  if (!$("input[name='typesport']:checked").val()) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
 Select the option that fits most to you<br><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="typesport" value="teamsport" > I prefer a teamsport</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="typesport" value="individual"> I prefer an individual sport</label><br>
 </p>
<a href="#question2" class="tm-bordered-btn next-button">Next question</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 supports the `required` attribute for radio buttons. I did some searching and [HTML5: How to use the "required" attribute with a "radio" input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field) has more detailed information about this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a radio button checked by default by using the `checked` attribute.

To check if it's checked or not, use this code :

```
  if ($('input[name=typesport]').attr('value') != undefined) {
    //execute code when it is checked
  } else {
    //execute code when it's not checked
  }
```