# How to use required attribute with multiple input tags

Tags: php, html

I have multiple input attributes for a Likert scale (1-5), where 1 is 'strongly disagree' and 5 is 'completely agree' as follows;

```
<li><input type="radio" name="likert" value="1"><label>1</label>
        <!--Strongly Disagree--></li>
<li><input type="radio" name="likert" value="2"><label>2</label></li>
```

etc.

Is there a way I can add the html boolean required attribute and wrap all these input statements so it can validate it through the browser to only continue if one input has been selected?

Thank you.

Comment: Set at least one input radio as `required`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field

Answer (score 0):

you need radio group. Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio) for example of using radio group.