# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel

I have a option tag to name 'status'.

blade

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3" for="status">Status</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="status" id="active" value="active">                        Active
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="status" id="deactive" value="deactive">                      Deactive
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'status']
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        SchoolsList::create($request->all());
        return redirect(route('submit-information.index'));
    }
```

When I click on submit I  see this error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a
>   default value

How to when select option value save and add to my database.

Comment: Which field type you have given to 'status'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field

I think you need to make the field required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's throwing this error. Because when you submit your form, status column has no value inside it. check your submitted form data & ensure that it has value. Otherwise, make your column nullable using `$this->integer('status')->nullable();`

Comment: I do not want to be empty. I want to save in database

Comment: have you checked your submitted data? share your output with us.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting anything from the radio button while submitting the value so the key status is having no value in it . Which is throwing you this error as the status column in db needs a value while inserting a new row  .

1 - Put some validation before submitting your form for status .

2 - Else go to your db and set a default value as active/deactive/null in the table manually .

3 - Else change the property of the "status attribute" in the table . (Make it varchar manually )

4 - If you are want to do it with code delete the table and create it by 
Laravel Schema Builder
[Click Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema)
and there make the status nullable .

```
  Schema::create('table_1',function ($table){
  $table->nullable('status'); // add other attibutes . refere the url });
```