# How do you validate multiple radio buttons at one time without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a validation function for a html code that was given to me for my class, but am not allowed to change the html code besides adding a head and script. I am at such an early stage that I don't know how to use jQuery yet and would like help with validation for the multiple radio buttons.

I have tried looking for the answer on this and many other sites and just can't seem to find it. I have tried multiple codes, but I suspect that all of them were made with jQuery.

The input for the html

```
<input type = "radio" name = "radNewsletter" value = "" />Health and Wellness<br />
<input type = "radio" name = "radNewsletter" value = "" />Creative Writing<br />
<input type = "radio" name = "radNewsletter" value = ""/>Gardening
```

The existing validation

```
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["frmNews"]["txtName"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            alert ("Name must be filled out.");
            return false;
            }
        var y = document.forms["frmNews"]["txtEmail"].value;
        if (y == "") {
            alert ("Email must be filled out.");
            return false;
            }
```

I was unable to get any other output than the form validating when I pressed the submit button, even when the existing validation should have stopped it.

Comment: what do you want to validate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field

Answer (score 2):

I found that `radNewsletter` is a common name in your form. In order to validate forms for radio buttons, you can use below code.

```js
function validateForm() {
        var radios = document.getElementsByName("radNewsletter");
        var formValid = false;

        var i = 0;
        while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
            if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
            i++;        
        }

        if (!formValid) alert("Must check some option!");
        console.log(formValid)
        return formValid;
    }
```

```html
<input type = "radio" name = "radNewsletter" value = "" />Health and Wellness<br />
<input type = "radio" name = "radNewsletter" value = "" />Creative Writing<br />
<input type = "radio" name = "radNewsletter" value = ""/>Gardening

<br />
<button onclick="validateForm()">Validate
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm() {

        var radios = document.getElementsByName("radNewsletter");

        if(!radios.checked)
        {
          alert("we are testing")
        }

         if(radios.checked = true){
           alert("your checking the boxs")
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector` and pusedo selector `checked`. This line `document.querySelector('input[name="radNewsletter"]:checked')` will give the first radio button with the name `radNewsletter` which is checked. On click of button check if this value is not `null`. Hopefully you can validate using this

```js
function validate() {

  let isChecked = document.querySelector('input[name="radNewsletter"]:checked');
  if (isChecked !== null) {
    console.log(isChecked.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radNewsletter" value="hw">Health and Wellness<br />
<input type="radio" name="radNewsletter" value="cw">Creative Writing<br />
<input type="radio" name="radNewsletter" value="g">Gardening<br/>


<button type='button' onclick='validate()'>Validate</button>
```